# KKT-like conditions for values close to optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient conditions for problems where we maximize over a convex function subject to linear inequality and equality constraints. That is $x^*$ is an optimal point iff it satisfies the KKT conditions.

My question is, are there similar necessary and/or sufficient conditions for points $x$ near $x^*$?

Comment: I've seen Delphine Mico-Umutesi give a talk "Estimating the Violation of the KKT Conditions" that has a similar flavor. You can find an abstract online, but I can't seem to find a full paper.